# Laravel where clause

Tags: php, laravel

I am trying to filter out objects by date. I am getting them by:

```
$events = Event::orderBy('event_date')->with('organizers')->get();
```

Which works fine...but now I'd like to split events to passed and not passed, so I tried with:

```
$result1 = $events->where('event_date', '<', Carbon::now());
```

But it returns empty collection. If I add `get()`, it gives me an error. Strangely enough, if I do it like:

```
$result1 = $events->where('is_featured', 1);
```

This works, and returns only featured elements. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: `it gives me an error.`.... error messages can be very useful for diagnosing problems; perhaps you'd enlighten us by telling us the error that you're getting

Comment: `Missing argument 1 for Illuminate\Support\Collection::get()`

Comment: Try doing something like `$events = Event::orderBy('event_date')->with('organizers')->where('event_date', '<', Carbon::now())->get();`

Comment: It is not what I want because I am fetching it in two places, and I would have to repeat the code. Can you tell me why my function doesn't work?

Comment: Perhaps because you're trying to apply the `where()` to a collection (the result of  previous query), not to a query, so it's being executed by the collection method which is doing a rather different comparison than the database where clause.

Answer (score 1):

As you state in your question, $events is a Collection, not a query. The where() method on the Collection works a little differently.

For Collections, the where() method does not accept an operator. It only does equality comparisons. The first parameter is the key, the second is the value, and the third is a boolean to flag a loose comparison (==) vs a strict comparison (===).

What you're looking for is the filter() method. You pass in a Closure that does your date comparison. If the Closure returns true, the item stays in the Collection. If it returns false, the item is removed from the Collection. Something like this (just an example, the logic may need to be tweaked):

```
$filteredEvents = $events->filter(function ($item) use ($date) {
    return (data_get($item, 'event_date') > $date) && (data_get($item, 'event_date') < $date->endOfDay());
});
```